# Should I create a "Student" model class if I have a CoreData Entity called "StudentEntity"?

Tags: core-data, model, swift3, entity, ios10

I am new to CoreData.
I'm building an ios 10 (Swift3) app with offline support. I need to save "Student" details in the app in CoreData.

I have managed to save in CoreData and Fetch the results by following this lesson.
[CoreData IOS10 Swift](https://learnappdevelopment.com/uncategorized/how-to-use-core-data-in-ios-10-swift-3/)

My question is how to maintain an entity model class like this?

```
class Student: NSObject {

    //Attributes
    var id:String = ""
    var contractNo:String = ""
    var name:String = ""

}
```

Sometimes, I need to get a student list from an API and save in "Students" dictionary then I might show a list of students in a "Tableview".

In Websites, we would have a table called "Users" and a corresponding model class call "User.php" which will handle all create/edit/delete/update actions.

I'm not very sure about the best way in IOS10 with Swift3. (It seems we don't need to create Student-CoreData NSManagedObject subclass in IOS10)

So I just named my CoreData entity "**StudentsEntity**"(to avoid ambiguous name error) and created a class called "**Student.swift**" inside the Models group.

Now I can do this

```
var studentArray:[Student] = [Student]()
```

Can any of those CoreData Gurus out there advise me on this? 
Can I continue to do this or is there a better way to achieve this workflow?
Any comments or suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you know already that Xcode is generating NSManagedObject subclasses for you?

Comment: Ok but can we use those classed to create dictionaries and arrays?